# Cannot access referenced object after session closed

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a class `DepartmentEntity`, includes a property named `Company(CompanyEntity)` as bellow:

```
public class DepartmentEntity
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DepartmentEntity Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyEntity Company { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyEntity
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`DepartmentEntity.hbm.xml` as bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
        <class name="HS.DepartmentEntity, HS" table="DepartmentInfo" lazy="true">
            <id name="ID">
                <generator class="identity" />
            </id>
            <property name="Name" not-null="true" />
            <many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentID" class="HS.DepartmentEntity, HS" cascade="none" unique="true" not-found="ignore" lazy="no-proxy" />
            <many-to-one name="Company" column="CompanyID" class="HS.CompanyEntity, HS" cascade="none" unique="true" not-found="ignore" lazy="no-proxy" />
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

`CompanyEntity.hbm.xml` as bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
        <class name="HS.CompanyEntity, HS" table="CompanyInfo" lazy="true">
            <id name="ID">
                <generator class="identity" />
            </id>
            <property name="Name" not-null="true" />
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

I tried the code bellow:

```
IList<DepartmentEntity> list; 
using(ISession session = GetSession()) 
{ 
    string hql = "FROM DepartmentEntity as dpe join fetch dpe.Company"; 
    list = session.CreateQuery(hql).List<DepartmentEntity>(); 
}
```

after session closed, property `Company` can not be accessed, but if the list method only found one record, the property `Company` can be accessed, I don't know why.

Comment: By 'I have a object', I assume you mean 'I have written a class called'. What do you mean by "visited"? Do you mean accessed? If so, I assume you're having trouble accessing it at runtime and you should be getting an exception that you could track down to get a better idea of what is going wrong. Could you show us the relevant parts of the `DepartmentEntity`-class and the `Company(CompanyEntity)`-property (even though I don't know other properties, with parameters, than indexed properties)?

Comment: @Aske B, I have updated the codes, FYI.

Comment: If I set lazy="proxy", it can works, but if I use DepartmentEntity entity = seestion.get<DepartmentEntity>(1), after session closed,property Company also can be accessed, it's not a lazy load now, but if I set lazy="no-proxy",entity = seestion.get<DepartmentEntity>(1), after session closed,property Company also can not be accessed, it's a lazy load, but all the entities in the list, property Company, can not be accessed.

Comment: Please, can you explain better the issue? I cannot figure the real issue you are telling about. I think there's an answer, but I need to be sure I well understood your problem! thanks

Comment: I tried to test your code, but generating the DDL from your mapping the results are not ... normal.. so please if you provide the DDL for the tables I can provide you an answer, and a code test case posted to my github space.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate uses the session object to Lazy load navigation properties. When you first access the navigation property, NHibernate accesses the data store and fetches the object's value using the session. When the session is closed, then an attempt to access the property throws an exception of type `NHibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

I would suggest you try to keep the session open while access to the Company property is required or you can switch off lazy loading (which may reduce the performance) of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your problem is after the closing the session , you are trying to load a lazy property. 
So you can do sth like this:

```
 if(!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(object.Lazy_property) )

         NHibernateUtil.Initialize(object.Lazy_property);
```

**BUT** it's gonna throw an exception that "collection is not associated with any session" so you have to open a session, add the object to session (I usually use session.saveorUpdate(object)) and then initialize the lazy property.

```
 if(!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(object.Lazy_property) )
```

{

```
         //open a session 
        session.SaveorUpdate(object);
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(object.Lazy_property);
        //close the session
```

}

**BUT** you still can get an exception that "Another instance with same ID is in Session" so you have to check if another instance with same id is in session. If you go through different documents they suggest you to check session.contains(object)  before adding object to the session.

```
 if(!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(object.Lazy_property) )
```

{

```
         //open a session 
         if (session.Contains(object))
             session.evict(object);
        Session.SaveorUpdate(object);
        NHibernateUtil.Initialize(object.Lazy_property);
        //close the session
```

}

**BUT** it still does not solve the problem. Because Contains method work on instances not on IDs.So a good approach is using Load method:

```
  if (!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(object.Lazy_property))
     {
      //open a session
       Class1 temp_object= lSession.Load<Class1>(object.ID);
       if (temp_object.ID == Object.ID)
            Session.Evict(lProgressItemType);

       Session.SaveOrUpdate(this);
       NHibernateUtil.Initialize(ProxyMilestoneList);
      //close session
       }
```

and the best approach is using both Load and Contains together:

```
  if (!NHibernateUtil.IsInitialized(object.Lazy_property))
     {
      //open a session
       Class1 temp_object= lSession.Load<Class1>(object.ID);
       if (temp_object.ID == object.ID && !Session.Contain(object))
            Session.Evict(lProgressItemType);

       Session.SaveOrUpdate(this);
       NHibernateUtil.Initialize(ProxyMilestoneList);
      //close session
       }
```

Because just by checking the ID, it is possible you remove an instance you want to work on it from session and then add it to session again. It doesn't throw any exception but you hit the DB twice.